# Sql Statement for last 24 hours

Tags: sql, sqlite

i got the following problem:

I have a sqlite3 database with the following column:
id, humidy, temp1, temp2, date, time

The date is formatted in `DD.MM.YYYY`
and the time is formatted in `HH:MM:SS`

Now i want to get the content for the last 24 hours.
Therefore i got a sql statement like:

```
SELECT *FROM messwerte
WHERE date BETWEEN date('now','-1 day') AND date('now')
```

But i have to connect the statement with the content of my time column.

Which is the correct sql statement for my problem?

Comment: Is your date value not stored as a date?

Answer (score 1):

Since your date and time values seem to be in a format SQLite does not recognize according to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) I think you have to create a valid datetime by parsing the date and time columns like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM messwerte
WHERE datetime(
  substr(date,7,4) 
  || '-' 
  || substr(date,4,2) 
  || '-' 
  || substr(date,1,2)
  || ' '
  || time
) BETWEEN datetime('now','-1 day') AND datetime('now');
```

The formatting of the datetime function used in the where clause is just for clarity and to avoid line breaks and is not needed.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e3abc/1)

On a side note: if you have access to, and can alter, the schema of the table and how data is inserted you might want to consider storing the date and time in one column only in the native (iso 8601 compatible) format that SQLite uses for dates, and then you wouldn't have to use functions to deal with your dates.